# running multiple MapReduce jobs in hadoop

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

I want to run a chain of map reduce jobs, so the easiest solution seems to be jobcontroller. say I have two jobs, job1 and job2. and I want to run job2 after job1. Well, it faced some problems. after hours of debugging, I narrowed down the code to these lines:

```
JobConf jobConf1 = new JobConf();  
JobConf jobConf2 = new JobConf();  
System.out.println("*** Point 1");
Job job1 = new Job(jobConf1);  
System.out.println("*** Point 2");
Job job2 = new Job(jobConf2);
System.out.println("*** Point 3");
```

I keep getting this output when running the code:

```
*** Point 1    
10/12/06 17:19:30 INFO jvm.JvmMetrics: Initializing JVM Metrics with processName=JobTracker, sessionId=
*** Point 2    
10/12/06 17:19:30 INFO jvm.JvmMetrics: Cannot initialize JVM Metrics with processName=JobTracker, sessionId= - already initialized
*** Point 3
```

What I guess is that my problem is related somehow to "cannot initialize JMV ...." line. What is that? And how I can instantiate more than one job, in order to pass them to JobController.

When I added job1.waitForTheCompletion(true) before initializing the second job, it gave me this error:

```
    10/12/07 11:28:21 INFO jvm.JvmMetrics: Cannot initialize JVM Metrics with processName=JobTracker, sessionId= - already initialized
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.InvalidInputException: Input path does not exist: file:/home/workspace/WikipediaSearch/__TEMP1
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat.listStatus(FileInputFormat.java:224)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.lib.input.FileInputFormat.getSplits(FileInputFormat.java:241)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.writeNewSplits(JobClient.java:885)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapred.JobClient.submitJobInternal(JobClient.java:779)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.submit(Job.java:432)
        at org.apache.hadoop.mapreduce.Job.waitForCompletion(Job.java:447)
        at ch.ethz.nis.query.HadoopQuery.run(HadoopQuery.java:353)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:65)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.ToolRunner.run(ToolRunner.java:79)
        at ch.ethz.nis.query.HadoopQuery.main(HadoopQuery.java:308)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
        at org.apache.hadoop.util.RunJar.main(RunJar.java:156)
```

__Temp1 is the output folder of the first job, which I want to be the input for the second one. And even though I have this waitForCompletion line in my code, it's still complaining that this path doesn't exist.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Wowww, after two days of debugging, it turns out that the problem is with hadoop internal directories names rule. Seemingly, for the input or output map-reduce directories, one cannot choose names starting with underline "_". That stupid!
And the warnings and error were no help at all.

Comment: Hadoop documentation is most certainly less than perfect.  I remember it took me forever to learn that subclasses of InputSplit have to implement Writable.  You'd think they'd mention that in the InputSplit documentation somewhere.  I still haven't managed to successfully run a hadoop job without packaging it into a jar first.

Answer (score 0):

Is it possible you can't create a job while another one hasn't finished?  I use hadoop 0.20.2 (note that JobConf is deprecated.  hadoop claims to support backwards compatibility but in my experience, it doesn't really) and I've done basically the same thing and never had that problem.  Do you still have the problem if you add job1.waitForCompletion(true) before job2 is created?

Comment: Hi, Yes Actually, I've tested all scenarios, including this one: for(int i=0; i<2; i++) { Job job = new Job(getConf(), "iteration");       InitializeTheJob;  job.wait.waitForCompletion(true);  }                 And still I keep getting the same warning. and then something new happened. I've updated the main question post so you can see the problem.